# Home user perpetual licence

Tags: licensing

I upgraded to 12.2 about 6 weeks ago. Since I'm a very casual user I just want the license, no support. I've gotten used, over the years, to avoiding all of the options that get offered. It seems as though I didn't read the small print well enough, and that now 12.2 no longer has a perpetual licence, only an annual one that is on top of the upgrade cost. I now get asked for my activation key, which it then says has expired.

I don't particularly want to downgrade (even if that is possible). So do I really have to shell out an extra 170 euros a year now for a licence?

(On re-reading the web site, it doesn't seem clear that time limited licensing is now being sold).

Comment: Your options are likely (a) contact support, since the user community has no role regarding financial dealings of WRI and (b) consider using a Raspberry Pi, which has a different license.

Comment: I see Mathematica | Desktop available here for 341 Euro for what appears to be a perpetual license: https://store.wolfram.com/view/app/mathematica/home

Comment: I have contacted Wolfram. Will update here when I get a reply.

Comment: @CarlLange I love how they have four stores for four categories of customer, and all four stores are the same.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, their sales funnel on their site is so weird, I have no idea who is supposed to navigate these things.

Comment: @CarlLange As for who might navigate such things, I am reminded of [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fdjf4lMmiiI) (I hope nobody I work with is paying attention).

Comment: My last two upgrades, I got a message after a few weeks that my license was about to expire. The first time, the program did indeed stop working. This required contacting Wolfram. They fixed it from their end and I got a message saying that the next tine I start the program it will work, and it did. I still don't understand why I have to get this done after each upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

The issue was solved by Wolfram Customer Support:

> This was a temporary activation while your order was processed. I have
> now fixed this and removed the expiration date. You can now activate
> your product fully using the same Activation Key.

Comment: Very nice, thank you for posting an update.